# separate_rows of full names in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

Suppose I have a dataset like this:

```
a <- c(1)
b <- ("Mr Mark Brown Ms Olivia Brown Mrs Alex Tyrwitt  Bryan Fox Dr Somebody Something")
ab <- cbind(a,b)
```

And I want to use `separate_rows`. But I can't because in `b` there is no comma or semicolon. Also notice that there might be a name that doesn't include any title. How could I split it in that case?

Comment: What is your expected output?  `cbind` returns a matrix by default.  Does a name have two words or have more than two (in addition to title)

Answer (score 1):

For the example you have provided, you can use `separate_rows` as follows

```
ab <- tibble(a = 1, b = "Mr Mark Brown Ms Olivia Brown Mrs Alex Tyrwitt  Bryan Fox Dr Somebody Something")

ab %>% separate_rows(b, sep = ' (Mr|Ms|Mrs||Dr) ')
```

For more complex examples, you can update the regular expression specified by `sep` to suit your purposes.